# console.log(myFunction()) returns undefined

Tags: javascript, undefined, console.log

I'm new to JavaScript, and I try to play around with it to understand all in-and-outs. I write

```
function greet() {
    console.log("Hi");
};

console.log(greet());
```

And the result of it in the console is

```
> Hi app.js:2 
> undefined app.js:4
```

I assume this is because `greet()` inside `console.log` first calls the function, which prints out `"Hi"`. We get first line of log. **But where did the second line come from?**

Then I thought because `Hi` is overall result of `greet()`, then `console.log` basically calls variable `Hi`, but in this case the result would be `is not defined`, not `undefined`

Comment: The return value of `greet()` is undefined so that is what you see as the log of line 4.

Comment: A function that has no specific `return` value returns `undefined` by default when executed. Check `console.log((function(){})())` in your browser's console.

Comment: `Hi` is not the overall result of `greet()`, the function simply logs a message to the console. Looks like you actually want `return "Hi";` Functions that do not have a `return` value specified return `undefined`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In JavaScript, if nothing is returned from the function with the keyword `return` then `undefined` is returned by default.

```
var data = greet();
console.log(data);// undefined, since your function does not return.
```

Is equivalent to:

`console.log(greet());`

The second output is the returned result from the function. Since you are not returning anything from the function hence prints `undefined`.

To print 'Hi' in the second console you have to return that from the function.

```js
function greet() {
  console.log("Hi");
  return 'Hi';
};

console.log(greet());
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a **return** keyword like this:

```
function greet() {
   console.log("HI");
   return "HI";
};
console.log(greet());
```

Or you can store it in a **variable** and return the **variable**:

```
function greet() {
   const hello = ("HI");
   return hello;
};
cosnole.log(greet());
```

,Because if you don't use ***return keyword*** and log the **function** to the console then it returns **undefined**.

Answer (score 0):

The default behaviour of javascript functions is to return something if we don't manually return anything it will automatically return undefined

As you have defined your function greet it is not returning anything so by default the function greet is returning undefined

Your function call should be made in this way

```
function greet(){
    return "Hi";
}
console.log(greet());
```