# Why does console.log return undefined after correct output?

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a very simple JS function and was wondering if the console returning 'undefined' after correctly logging every function call was normal or an error as a result of a badly written function.

```
const getWeather = function(country, weatherType) {
    console.log('The weather in ' + country + ' is ' + weatherType + '.');
}

console.log(getWeather('Scotland', 'sunny'));
console.log(getWeather('Japan', 'beautiful'));
console.log(getWeather('Germany', 'frosty'));
```

Comment: The function doesn't return anything.  What are you expecting to be logged to the console in those last three lines?

Comment: `console.log()` *always* returns `undefined`, which in JavaScript just means it didn't return anything.

Comment: Either change the `console.log` inside the function to `return`, or just remove it from the function calls below.

Comment: You already have console.log in getWeather, do need to put getWeather in console.log again. So either return string from function and then console log it, or you console log inside function.

Comment: @David Apologies, I probably shouldn't have used the word 'returned'. The console logs "The weather in Scotland is sunny" followed by 'undefined' after that, then the next log is "The weather in Japan is beautiful" and another 'undefined' under this and so on.

Comment: hey guys, this isn't a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14633968/chrome-firefox-console-log-always-appends-a-line-saying-undefined, he's calling console.log twice not questioning why console.log returns undefined.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [console.log(myFunction()) returns undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48362507/console-logmyfunction-returns-undefined)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the other commenters have said, console.log doesn't return anything so the result is *always* undefined. It looks like you actually want to return the generated string from your function and then log that. Try the following:

```
const getWeather = function(country, weatherType) {
    return 'The weather in ' + country + ' is ' + weatherType + '.';
}

console.log(getWeather('Scotland', 'sunny')); // The weather in Scotland is sunny.
console.log(getWeather('Japan', 'beautiful')); // The weather in Japan is beautiful.
console.log(getWeather('Germany', 'frosty')); // The weather in Germany is frosty.
```

What happens in your original code is that you call your function and log the message inside of it. Your function doesn't return anything so when you attempt to log the output of that function you are logging *undefined*.

Comment: Brilliant. This has worked. Thank you @Chris and all other commenters who also pointed out the same error. Much appreciated.